# does "sensitive plate" refers to "Photographic plate" or not?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

does "sensitive plate" refers to "Photographic plate" or not?

> The author is of opinion that the true explanation will be found by
>   coupling all these happenings with the recent investigations of Dr.
>   Crawford upon the means by which physical phenomena are produced. He
>   showed very clearly, as is detailed in a subsequent chapter, that raps
>   (we are dealing at present only with that phase) are caused by a
>   protrusion from the medium's person of a long rod of a substance
>   having certain properties which distinguish it from all other forms of
>   matter. This substance has been closely examined by the great French
>   physiologist, Dr. Charles Richet, who has named it "ectoplasm." These
>   rods are invisible to the eye, partly visible to **the sensitive plate**,
>   and yet conduct energy in such a fashion as to make sounds and strike
>   blows at a distance.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: Was a photographic plate mentioned earlier?

Comment: @Fivesideddice no. but Photographic plate was very close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1859, when Conan Doyle was born, the term 'sensitive plate' was just starting to be used to describe a glass plate coated with light-sensitive chemicals. The term was still in use in 1888 when [this edition](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=jxh1coMDpxYC&pg=PA330&lpg=PA330&dq=sensitive%20plate%20camera&source=bl&ots=dB97YbFjjj&sig=ACfU3U0cRWCfQV3V2wrQ0PScZheCMJQYwA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjatoenjsfoAhVabn0KHZ6LCTkQ6AEwGHoECA0QLw#v=onepage&q=sensitive%20plate%20camera&f=false) of the Photographic News was published but, as this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sensitive%20plate%2C%20photographic%20plate&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csensitive%20plate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphotographic%20plate%3B%2Cc0) shows, from then on the term was quite rapidly overtaken by 'photographic plate'.

Conan Doyle published the collection of essays "The history of spiritualism" in 1926. The term 'sensitive plate' was still in use but 'photographic plate' was nearing its peak, however Conan Doyle was nearly seventy by then, and can perhaps be forgiven for using the older term.

Comment: It's even more confusing to the modern reader because ACD's subject matter here includes repeated  references to ***sensitive*** as a ***noun*** usage (meaning *people who are sensitive to paranormal phenomena*). Given that photographic technology wouldn't have been familiar to many readers, they'd naturally be inclined to interpret ***sensitive plate*** as specifically implying *plate capable of / **designed for** capturing images of the supernatural that are normally invisible*. Perhaps ACD chose to use that slightly odd term specifically for that reason.

Comment: Note that Conan Doyle was ***born*** in 1859. *The History of Spiritualism* was first published in **1926** (by which time "the sensitive plate" was *way* past its sell-by date! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, oops... I read the wrong date from the web site. Thank you for pointing that out: I have updated my answer.